# terminal emulator for ncurses applications

Tags: term

What is the recommended terminal emulator in emacs to use ncurses applications? I use things like wicd-curses, cmake and other applications with rich ncurses interfaces and I am having trouble in finding an appropriate configuration where keyboard interaction works well and terminal content is not accidentally scrambled.

Thank you.

Comment: ansi-term is recommended. if something doesn't work it it you can write an emacs package to wrap a non-curses version of the tool (plain old wicd in this case)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an Emacs package for terminal emulation?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68491/is-there-an-emacs-package-for-terminal-emulation)

Comment: You might try [Eat](https://codeberg.org/akib/emacs-eat) or Vterm (needs C module).

Answer (score 2):

`ansi-term` is a terminal emulator, and appears to work well enough to support ncurses applications.

There are some sticky issues with terminfo, particularly after sshing into remote systems, http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints#toc6 has discussion about this.

Comment: Thank you. ansi-term works ok for things like top and cmake, but not for wicd-curses. I don't understand what the difference is!

Comment: Not familiar with wicd-curses, I've used it with aptitude and it worked, but certainly didn't do an exhaustive test of ncurses apps under `ansi-term`.